# Is there any way to reset mysql IDLE/Sleep connections?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, amazon-web-services

I have a problem, my app have to open a lot of connections with MySQL and write data into it, but for after some time I'm getting more and more connections that are in idle/sleep state, and my app's speed reduces until it completely stops. I blame `'wait_timeout'` variable to be too high,

```
mysql> show variables like '%timeout%';
+----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name              | Value    |
+----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout            | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout     | 300      |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout   | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout        | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout          | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout           | 30       |
| net_write_timeout          | 60       |
| slave_net_timeout          | 3600     |
| wait_timeout               | 28800    |
+----------------------------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.05 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| Id   | User     | Host                                               | db          | Command | Time | State | Info                  |
+------+----------+----------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+------+-------+-----------------------+
| 5425 | root     | ip-10-xxxxxxxx.ec2.internal:60544                 | my_db  | Sleep   | 2344 |       | NULL                  |
| 5426 | root     | ip-10-xxxxxxxx.ec2.internal:60561                 | my_db  | Sleep   | 2136 |       | NULL                  |
```

And there are a lot of connections like this.
So my primary question is how to reset connection? I know I can just `kill PID` but I would really like to reset it.

And do you think wait_timeout would solve an issue. By the way everything is on the Amazon RDS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that `wait_timeout` is probably the wrong solution, because, as @datasage implied, your application may not handle it gracefully.  The solution is for your application to properly close the connections when it is finished with them.

`KILL thread_id` is the correct way to reset it from the server side, but that's just a patch for the actual solution, assuming this is actually what's slowing down your application.

I commonly have hundreds of sleeping threads on my MySQL servers, because the application holds them in a pool for reuse.  Sleeping threads are sleeping.  They aren't slowing anything down unless you have so many of them that you're hitting the `max_connections` limit on RDS.

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce `wait_timeout` but you will need to be confident that your application can handle a connection being closed by the server instead of the client.